# Docker-compose builds but app does not serve on localhost

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, docker-compose, yaml

Docker newbie here.  Docker-compose file builds without any issues but when I try to run my app on localhost:4200, I get a message - localhost didn't send any data on chrome and the server unexpectedly dropped the connection in safari.  I am working on MacOs Catalina. Here is my yml file:

```json
version: '3.0' 

services:
  my-portal:

    build: .

    ports:
    - "4200:4200"

    depends_on:
    - backend

  backend: 

   build: ./backend

   ports:
    - "3000:3000"

   environment:

      POSTGRES_HOST: host.docker.internal
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypwd

   depends_on:
    -db

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine

    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypwd
      POSTGRES_HOST: host.docker.internal

    ports:
    - 5432:5432
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Log for Angular:

> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
> Log for Node: db connected
> Log for Postgres: database system is ready to accept connections

Below are my Angular and Node Docker files:

```
FROM node:latest AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod
EXPOSE 4200
# Stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/*  /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Node:

```
FROM node:12    
WORKDIR /backend    
COPY package*.json ./    
RUN npm install    
COPY . .    
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

When I created Angular image and ran my app on `localhost:4200` it worked fine.  Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Angular container is built `FROM nginx`, and you use the default Nginx configuration from the [Docker Hub `nginx` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).  That listens on port 80, so that's the port number you need to use in use `ports:` directive:

```yaml
services:
  quickcoms-portal:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "4200:80" # <-- second port must match nginx image's port
    depends_on:
    - backend
```

The `EXPOSE` directive in the first stage is completely ignored and you can delete it.  The `FROM nginx` line causes `docker build` to basically completely start over from a new base image, so your final image is stock Nginx plus the files you `COPY --from=builder`.